# Unable to configure audio on HP Pavilion G6 2006AX - using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Tags: 12.04, sound, ati, alsa, hp-pavilion

I recently installed Ubuntu 12.04 LTS version on my HP Pavilion G6 2006AX laptop. This is the *only* operating system that I have on my laptop (no dual boot).

Processor & Graphics detail: AMD A6-4400M APU with Radeon(tm) HD Graphics × 2

I installed AMD catalyst 12.11 beta11 driver to support the Graphics card. Seems like it is doing OK.

Unfortunately, I am not able to configure my audio drivers and it just shows up as speaker icon with a dash dash dash next to it.

Is there anyway that I can help you troubleshoot this issue? (like config, logs etc.) I am sure other HP Pavilion G6 users might have faced this...I am unable to find a solution after searching Ask Ubuntu forums.

running *alsamixer* on commandline...provides the following info:

```
Card: HD-Audio Generic
Chip: ATI R6xx HDMI
```

Answer (score 3):

Phew! After going through quite a number of Ubuntu forums and even changing over to XUbuntu 12.04 (precise pangolin) installation, I was finally able to arrive at a solution to get sound working on my laptop.

I strongly recommend anyone having similar issue to go through [Sound Troubleshooting - Ubuntu Forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1885240).

There are different default combination of drivers offered by Ubuntu. Pulse Audio, ALSA and then Open Sound Linux drivers (oss-linux). The suggested steps is focussed on ALSA.

In my case, I had to follow the following steps:

**Step 1:**

I completely cleared the contents of file */etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf* and just added the following:

```
options snd-hda-intel index=0 model=auto
```

**Step 2:**

Downloaded the relevant ALSA audio development package relevant to Ubuntu 12.04 from the [following site](https://code.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-audio-dev/+archive/alsa-daily/+packages). It was alsa-hda-dkms_0.201301181937~precise1_all.deb.

```
sudo dpkg -i alsa-hda-dkms_0.201301181937~precise1_all.deb
```

If the above step complains that dkms package is missing, do the following:

```
sudo apt-get install dkms
```

**Step 3:**

Reboot the system. When you log back in, you can try the following to see the list of sound devices on your system (the following was present in my laptop):

```
sudo aplay -l

**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: HDMI [HDA ATI HDMI], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: Generic [HD-Audio Generic], device 0: STAC92xx Analog [STAC92xx Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

**Step 4:**

On terminal, open alsamixer and unmute the master volume and adjust sound levels and try playing a sample audio file.

Good luck!